# Voltage of Logic Low on ICs

Tags: integrated-circuit, breadboard

I'm currently trying to create a 4 bit ALU using the [CD4011BE](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4011b.pdf) quad 2-input CMOS  NAND gate ICs. However, I'm having some trouble when creating the full adders. Sometimes, when the IC outputs logic low, I'm getting 2.5V, which causes the next NAND gate to also output something like 2.5V. This carries down to the sum, which is 2.5V when supposed to be under 0.5V. I've read that ICs need decoupling capacitors, but I'm not sure if that would cause this problem

I'm testing this on a Breadboard, and running 5V rails.

EDIT: I've tried testing the voltage of each pin. Strangely, the ground pin had 1.5V while only being connected to ground. I tried replugging everything in, and it worked perfectly now.

Comment: You might want to add a schematic, so we can spot an error in your design (maybe) rather then guessing what might be wrong.

Comment: What Arsenal said, also do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: The fact that your supply is 5V and that the circuits are CMOS logic means that any well defined output should be either 0 V or 5V. If you get 2.5 V I think one or more of the inputs of the gates are not connected. With CMOS logic you must always define all inputs, so tie them to ground or +5V.

Comment: Logic gate levels MUST always lie inside defined limits. If they do not SOEMTHING is wrong. There are only two things that can be wrong (with lots of subthings inside these two things.
(1) One or more ICs are damaged. (2) YOU are doing something wrong. SO||  - Measure ALL supply voltage and ground pins - all should be 5 or 0 v within fairly tight limits. - Measure ALL input s that you have control over. ALL should be at ~= 5V or ~= 0V. All MUST be above Vinhi_min or below Voinlow_max. Fix silly mistakes. - Then measure Vin's that you have no control over ....

Comment: .... (eg driven by outputs). Any wrong - work out why - fix. || If ANY lvels are still wrong IC'(s) are damaged or you have missed something. |||| Floating inputs -> death. | Shorted hi or lo output -> death. | Load resistor too small -> .... | Too many gate inputs on an output (fanout exceeded -> ... . |

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Other possibility is oscillation or other square wave with 50% duty cycle being measured by a multimeter. No bypass capacitors..but more likely an open input picking up mains frequency. Measuring the input shows 0V (looks fine, output takes a proper logic level but he can't see it), move the probe to output, it's back to 2.5V.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes - oscillation can present as an apparent DC value and I did not specifically cover that (or remember to include it even though I'm all too familiar with it over the years). However, what I said would largely cover that (Vin near rails, no floating inputs, ...) BUT yes, oscillation should be checked for.

Comment: @Oswinso - as Spehro says- it is possible for ICs to have oscillating outputs which can look like an intermediate DC voltage to a meter set to DC volts. If you do what I suggested above (no open inputs, all inpouts inside rated ranges high or low) it should usually be OK BUT adding decoupling capacitors to the power supply rails is essentially essential.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks for all your comments. I've replugged the wires, and it now works perfectly despite not having made any changes. I'm not quite sure how to add decoupling capacitors though. Should I place one in front of every VDD and VSS of the IC?

Comment: You had a bad connection somewhere in your solderless breadboard, more than likely it **will** come back to bite you.